# How to create a function to use every react file without importing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const print = console.log.bind(document)
```

Hi all. For above example i want to use `print` function instead of `console.log` function in every react file without importing. How can i do that ?

Comment: `window.print = console.log.bind(document)`. The `window` object is the global scope.

Comment: Should that be `console.log.bind(console)` instead?

Comment: @Thomas I think print is already a global method. It’s probably best not to override that

Comment: Ah yes, people used to use actual printers in the past :D

Comment: Both didnt work. When i try window.p = console.log.bind(console) and window.p = console.log.bind(document) and when i try to use another in js file. I get 'p' is not defind error.

Answer (score 0):

The way suggested in the comments should work in javascript, given that the definition of
the function is done before the function is used, e.g.:

```
// -- file A.js:

window.p = console.log;

export const A = function( props ){
    p('log A');
    return <>A</>;
};

// -- file B.js:

export const B = function( props ){
    p('log B');
    return <>B</>;
};

// -- file App.js:

import React from 'react';
import { A } from './A';
import { B } from './B';

function App() {
    p('log App');
    return <><A /><B /></>;
}

export default App;
```

#### Es-lint

However, [es-lint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/) might still throw an error. To solve that, you can

- disable es-lint altogether, or
- add a comment `/*global p*/` in each file (which probably defeats the purpose of not having to import `p`, or write additional code to be able to use `p`), or
- set `no-undef` inside the `.eslintrc.js` file

Setting `no-undef` in `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
var OFF = 0, WARN = 1, ERROR = 2;

module.exports = exports = {
    "rules": {
        "no-undef": WARN, // or OFF
    }
};
```

*Note: When I tried this, apparently creating an `.eslintrc.js` file alone prevented the error (?). That may be caching issues that I don't understand.
Note you might have to remove `/node_modules/.cache` to make changes take effect,*